# What are the minimal permissions required to run Enable-Mailbox via Exchange Powershell?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

We want a user that is only able to create mailboxes (`Enable-Mailbox`) for any user in our AD on any of our mailbox servers.

So far, we've seen a range of suggestions as far as what permissions are required for that. [Microsoft's documentations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132.aspx) isn't clear either. Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Mail Recipient Creation** role allows an individual to *create* a recipient.  The **Mail Recipients** role enables a user to *manage existing* boxes.

It sounds like you want the **Mail Recipient Creation** role.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876911.aspx